# Unable to delete docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-container, docker-image

I am getting the following error when I execute `docker image rm -f command` and I am not able to delete the docker images from my system even after using force option.Please help to resolve it.Even prune command is also giving the same error.

```
Error: error reading image "5325e37426255f971e691f20b068b47d71dd3be62bd8bf22c5f6d23964bd4a44" as image: error locating item named "manifest" for image with ID "5325e37426255f971e691f20b068b47d71dd3be62bd8bf22c5f6d23964bd4a44": file does not exist
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove a container or an image?

Comment: i am trying to remove an image

Comment: Why don't you try `docker rmi <image-id>`?

Comment: I tried that as well.I am getting same error.

Comment: `docker rmi -f 5325e3` Did you try it this way?

Comment: yes, i tried the same command that you shared. But I still see the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251086/discussion-between-dreambold-and-eli-johnes).

Comment: Please let me know if there is a way to delete the image in this case